# Vue.js + Webpack-Dev-Server CSS URL's

Tags: webpack, vue.js, webpack-dev-server

I'm integrating Vue.js into an multi-page PHP application ( Not an SPA )
I'm using the vue-cli webpack template. Only modification i've made to the default template is adding multiple entry points (for generating multiple scripts for multiple pages)

For my development environment, I use docker-compose and serve the pages VIA my lamp stack and run the Webpack-dev-server on a separate instance and link the JS files generated by webpack-dev-server.

(* diagram of my setup )
[image: docker-compose]

My issue is getting the CSS url's from the webpack-dev-server instance.
I'm able to link in the JS files a-ok, and the 'build' outputs both the JS & CSS files perfectly. I've tried adding the ExtractTextPlugin with the filename param in my dev config, but still not able to source the CSS file from the webpack-dev instance.

Any advice would be much appreciated as I'm just getting into webpack

Thanks
-J

Comment: `the 'build' outputs both the JS & CSS files perfectly` you mean the problem is not linking the css generated to your html?

Comment: I'm using the default webpack config. https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack .  Correct, the build separates the JS and CSS, howerver, when running the webpack-dev-server ( for hot-reload ) The dev-server exposed the JS link ( IE 0.0.0.0:8080/[entry-point].js ) however I'm unable to link to the CSS files using the same convention... I tried using the same ExtractTextPlugin in the 'build' but still unable to reach the CSS files..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out the configuration

config/vue-loader.conf.js has a property `extract` when set to true adds the ExtractTextPlugin as the last loader to output a file. Set this to true for your dev.conf

Then, in your dev configuration, add the ExtractTextPlugin to your plugin stack and add the `filename` convention you want to source your file as.

NOTE: you will also need to configure the public path on the devServer config to be your containers {host}:{port}

I've forked the source template and added the configuration for reference/use

https://github.com/ibejohn818/vuejs-webpack-docker

Hope this helps somebody as I can see this as a common use-case and was unable to find any exact reference after days of googling.